# Samsung Galaxy S Firmware Update

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, 2.1-eclair, updates, device-firmware

I'm experiencing trouble with the 2.1 to 2.2 update. It looks like [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5031/how-can-i-install-official-android-2-2-froyo-in-samsung-galaxy-s-which-runs-andro) advice doesn't work for me as I have no Software Update button. I also tried [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6260/now-i-can-connect-but-not-able-to-upgrade-samsung-galaxy-s-gt-i9000-why) advice but it seems that I'm not able to put it in the download mode (it just doesn't apper). Can someone help me with the issue?

I also have next message in KIES:

[image: version]

As to KIES:

[image: kies]

My firmware version is 2.1-update1.

Comment: You have installed the latest version of KIES , haven't you ? I had issues with previous versions, but updating to the latest version on my Windows 7 pc allowed me to upgrade to the latest version (2.2.1).

Comment: Check out edit.

Comment: @den-avamaniac: Ok, that should do it , although I have version 2.0.0.11032_12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer on that other question wasn't quite right -- I have a US variant on the Galaxy S, and the process to get into download mode isn't exactly the same.  I'll update that answer shortly, in the meantime here are the Odin instructions:

Go to [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=846913) and download the newest firmware for your region.  Download [Odin for Windows](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9088113&postcount=1) (search for "Heimdall" if you are on Linux).  Then do the following:

1. [Put your phone into Download mode](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=Samsung_Galaxy_S_Series#Download_Mode)

   1. Remove the battery
   2. Hold VolumeDown plus the Home key plus Power.  While holding,

      1. Reinsert the battery.
      2. Release the Power button, still holding the others, about 1 second after the white "GT-I9000" text appears.
      3. After a few seconds a yellow triangle with an android in it should appear, this is Download Mode.  If it doesn't, try this again while holding Power the whole time.
2. Start up Odin.
3. Attach the phone to your PC via USB so that Odin recognizes it.
4. Load the .zip file you downloaded (the ROM/firmware) into the PDA field of Odin.
5. Load the 512 .pit file into the PIT field of Odin.
6. Check "Re-partition".
7. Hit Start.  Odin will tell you when it's done; if it fails, reboot your phone and try again.  (This happens occasionally).

Note that if you need to back anything up, you should do that beforehand and save the backup to your PC, since everything (except probably the external SD card) will be wiped on the phone.  Also note that you do this at your own risk; Odin is very powerful and misusing it can damage your phone.  I've used it dozens of times myself safely.

Comment: What's odin official site?

Comment: There is no official site for Odin, it's an internal Samsung tool that has been leaked.  If you're worried about the download, I have downloaded it from the location I linked and used it, with no problems.

Comment: What actually worries me is that most people have the Update Software button. And that I shouldn't be going through all this just to get it updated. :)

Comment: Understandable.  One would think that Kies would offer you the update, since it's detecting that you don't have 2.2 yet.

Comment: Great, the download mode works. That's a real progress. :)

Comment: What are the know/possible consequences of inappropriate Odin usage?

Comment: The main problem is if you flash a bad ROM (corrupt download or firmware for the wrong device) it can brick your phone.  In most cases when something goes wrong you can still get the phone into Download mode even if it won't boot, and Odin can be used to undo the damage.  I've used Odin lots without problems, but if you're unsure about anything do feel free to ask.

Comment: Funny, but it seems that the problem is actually in the network segment, from which I tried to update the system. It's super secure and has extremely filterable traffic, and it allows only certain range of ports to be used. And it looks like Sumsung is trying to be smart and use certain own security. :) Though this way should be working. Thanx.